# Convergence Domain of a Function Series

Tags: calculus

I am trying to calculate the convergence domain of the following function series. Would appreciate any hint.

$f_n(x)=\frac{nx^{n-1}}{1+x^{2n}}$

Edit: I've tried doing the limit as $n$ goes to $\infty$. I got that it converges when $|x|>1$ and $|x|<1 it should also converge. Thanks

Comment: No I don't have any additional info.

Comment: You need to take $n\to\infty$ and see what is the limit. Have you tried doing that?